# Renaming a button to 'processing' while the form is processing in next.js

Tags: next.js13

I'm trying to duplicate a functionality from React in Next.js where when the user clicks the Login button, 'Processing' replaces the name of the button after which when finished it goes back to 'Login'. This is how I did it in react:

```
import { useNavigation } from 'react-router-dom';

const isSubmitting=useNavigation().state==='submitting'
......................

return(
    <Form method='POST' action='/' >
       ......................
       <Button handleClick={handlerLogin}>{isSubmitting?'Processing...':'Login'}</Button>
       ......................
```

I'm not sure if I could use the `useNavigation` hook in Next.js. How could I duplicate this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for form management I discovered an interesting library: [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/overview)

I think it is a convenient one for grouping a set of inputs without using too many refs or useState and without using a state manager.

Internally manages the status of "Submitting":

```
 onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
         setTimeout(() => {
           alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
           setSubmitting(false); //with this instruction you can toggle the isSubmitting state
         }, 400);
       }}
```

And when you render the fom you have access to the state:

```
<button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
   Submit
</button>
```

or in your case:

```
<button type="submit">
   {
      isSubmitting?
      "processing...":
      "login"
   }
</button>
```